# Requests from Ec2 blocked by website despite Proxymesh

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, http-proxy, scrapy-splash

I’m using scrapy and scrapy_splash to scrape text data and take png screenshots from a series of websites. In accordance with best practices I’m using Proxymesh, the rotating IP service. My project was working on my local machine, but when I deployed to an Ec2 instance spiders two of my websites were getting completely blocked.

After some investigation I realized that curling these websites from my instance also failed so it was likely that these two websites are blocking all requests from AWS IP addresses. But then I remembered I’m using the Proxymesh service to make requests which worked from my local machine.

I understand why websites would block all AWS IP addresses, but why am I still having issues when I’m passing requests through Proxymesh? Do I need to pass requests to a VPN and then on to Proxymesh? How might I implement that in my scrapy_splash project?

All requests from scrapy are passed to Proxymesh via the http proxy environment variable:

```
export https_proxy=https://proxy:port
```

Splash gets the proxy in arguments passed to the request.

```
# Pass url to splash for screenshoting.
splash_args = {
                     'wait': 3.0,
                     'html': 1,
                     'png': 1,
                     'width': 600,
                     'render_all': 1,
                     'wait': 3.0,
                     'proxy':'http://<MYPROXYCREDS>:@proxy.crawlera.com:8010'
                                    }

yield SplashRequest(response.url,
                    self.create_screenshot,
                    endpoint='render.json',
                    args=splash_args,
                    meta={'ip_address': ip_address,
                                'title': title,
                                'filename': filename,
                                'server': server})
```

Comment: can we see what you've done so far? Splash has separate settings for proxies, even if you have proxy settings set on scrapy, splash requests are not routed through scrapy's system.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you say *"to avoid getting blocked"*... If you are getting blocked, this implies that you are doing something unauthorized, because sites do not typically make a practice of blocking authorized traffic yet many sites specifically forbid scraping.  Asking for help accomplishing something a site does not want you to accomplish does not seem appropriate.

Comment: @Verbal_Kint it's not just that splash requests aren't going through, no requests from scrapy or splash are going through.

Comment: I've tried switching to Crawlera as a solution, but it only partially works. Still trying to understand why Proxymesh doesn't work, but Crawlera does (with many errors). Why would Proxymesh work locally, but not from Ec2? Are these sites able to see my AWS IP address even when I'm behind Proxymesh?

Comment: without seeing the responses you're getting it is impossible to say what the problem is. Are you getting http response 200? 404? What are the errors? Have you tried sending a request to a test site (like httpbin,org/ip or https://nghttp2.org/httpbin/ip) with your proxy settings activated to see if your requests are actually getting routed appropriately? Without knowing what you've attempted specifically or at least seeing these "errors" you mention it is impossible to tell